# Is there a way to have a variable value equal to text? Trying to display a user-chosen word in the middle of an fprintf line

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to code a MadLibs-type game in Octave on a Mac, and can't figure out how to display a user-chosen WORD in the middle of a string of text. I used fprintf to display the sentence with the variable in the middle and it works just fine as long as the variable is equal to a NUMBER. If you enter anything other than a number you get an error.

```
    Word=input('Enter a word:            ');
    fprintf('You chose %d as the word.\n', Word)
```

How would I allow the user to chose a word, then display that word in the middle of a string of text?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [format specifier](https://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/fprintf.html) for `strings` is `%s` thus you can change your snippet to:

```
fprintf('You chose %s as the word.\n', Word)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked great and the project is well on its way.

Comment: @eftir awesome glad I could help! Please feel free to mark one of the answers as accepted if your question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

Input has the option of returning the entered text as a MATLAB string, without evaluating expressions.

```
STR = input(PROMPT,'s')
```

So that whatever is entered will be output as a string.
for your example:

```
Word=input('Enter a word:            ','s');
fprintf('You chose %d as the word.\n', Word)
```

Numbers or text will display correctly.

Comment: for the 's' parameter to input, but the correct format specifier for strings is %s, not %d. +1